# Cloning multidimensional form elements maintaining the right numbering (JQuery)

Tags: jquery

Given the following structure

```
<div class="form_segment">
<input type="text" name="data[0][sku]">
<input type="text" name="data[0][product]">
<input type="text" name="data[0][qty]">
</div>

<div class="form_segment">
<input type="text" name="data[1][sku]">
<input type="text" name="data[1][product]">
<input type="text" name="data[1][qty]">
</div>
```

I want to dynamically add such segments to the input form by pressing a button.

The problem is, to my knowledge I would do this by storing the index number in some attribute for the div, but since these segments could be deleted in the future, this would get absolutely messy and I'm sure there's a better solution.

So my question exactly is: how do I set the right index after cloning the div with jquery less painfully than my abovementioned idea?

Comment: at least you should define what is considered as ***right numering***. Indexing anything dynamically should always require ***some kind of tracking***. The most simplest form of tracking is based on the running variable of a for-loop.

Comment: right numbering is if i had 16 elements and delete 10 input segments from random places, i would get data with indexes 0,1,2,3,4,5,6...

I'm not sure where to implement a for loop anyways, my current code is a simple jquery clone call, calling count on the segments, and updating the newly inserted input indexes by that